# Defaulted concept-constrained function never selected for instantiation

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

While working with C++20, I encountered an oddity which I'm unsure is a compiler defect due to C++20's infancy, or whether this is correct behavior.

The problem is that a specific constrained function is either not selected correctly, or produces a compile-error -- depending entirely on the order of the definitions.

This occurs in specific circumstance:

- A constructor / destructor / member-function is constrained by `requires`, and
- This constructor / destructor / member-function is implicitly deleted for some instantiation of `T` that *does not satisfy the `requires` clause*

For example, consider this basic `naive_optional<T>` implementation:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class naive_optional {
public:
    naive_optional() : m_empty{}, m_has_value{false}{}

    ~naive_optional() requires(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>) = default;
    ~naive_optional() {
        if (m_has_value) {
            m_value.~T();
        }
    }
private:
    struct empty {};
    union {
        T m_value;
        empty m_empty;
    };
    bool m_has_value;
};
```

This code works fine for trivial types like `naive_optional<int>`, but fails to instantiate for non-trivial types such as `naive_optional<std::string>` due to an implicitly deleted destructor:

```
<source>:26:14: error: attempt to use a deleted function
    auto v = naive_optional<std::string>{};
             ^
<source>:8:5: note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here
    ~naive_optional() requires(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>) = default;
    ^
<source>:17:11: note: destructor of 'naive_optional<std::basic_string<char>>' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'm_value' has a non-trivial destructor
        T m_value;
          ^
1 error generated.
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/77YKbGn6j)</kbd>

If the order of definitions is changed so that the constrained function is below the unconstrained one, this works fine -- but instead selects the unconstrained function every time:

```cpp
...
    ~naive_optional() { ... }
    ~naive_optional() requires(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>) = default;
...
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/PYoE5K1bj)</kbd>

---

My question is ultimately: is this behavior *correct* -- am I misusing `requires`? If this is correct behavior, is there any simple way to accomplish conditionally `default`-ing a constructor / destructor / function that is not, itself, a template? I was looking to avoid the "traditional" approach of inheriting base-class implementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is correct, and indeed was the motivating example for supporting this sort of thing (see [P0848](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0848r3.html), of which I am one of the authors). Clang simply doesn't implement this feature yet (as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)).

gcc and msvc both [accept your code](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/v1Eda7M8q).

---

Note that you don't need `empty` anymore, just `union { T val; }` is sufficient in C++20, thanks to [P1331](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1331r2.pdf). [Demo](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/qTaahPvhn).

Comment: Wow, thanks this is truly an awesome answer -- it's succinct and provides all the necessary sources/details. I didn't check MSVC, but I did notice that `gcc` accepted the code, which is why I wasn't sure if this was a language or compiler issue (I probably should have added that to the question). Also awesome to know about the `union { T val; }` -- this is entirely new to me.