# What's the right way to partially initialize a struct?

Tags: c++, aggregate-initialization

For a user-defined allocator, the relation between the allocated-units must be constructed at the beginning, while the memory space for elements should be left uninitialized.

A simple demo:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T _item;
    Node* _prev;
    Node* _next;
};

template <typename T, typename ParentAllocator>
class MyAllocator {
    using Allocator = std::allocator_traits<ParentAllocator>::rebind_alloc<Node<T>>;
    Allocator _allocator;
    Node<T> _header;
    /* ... */

public:
    MyAllocator()
        : _allocator()
    {
        _header._prev = &_header;
        _header._next = &_header;

        // leaving `_item` uninitialized 
    }

    T* allocate(/*one*/) {
        auto* newNode = _allocator.allocate(1);
        newNode->_prev = &_header;
        newNode->_next = _header._next;

        // leaving `_item` uninitialized 

        /* ... */
        return &(newNode->_item);
    }
};
```

`Node` is not initialized, instead direct initialization for its members, though not for all.

My questions are:

1. Are `_header` and `_next` really partially initialized as expectations, even if the default constructor of `T` (both normal and `explicit` one) were deleted.
2. Have I implemented it properly?
3. If not, what's the right way?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Just a simple demo as I said. Generally the element of `MyAllocator` is a chunk (which contains a buffer for reducing the pressure of allocation and deallocation). `new` operator will evoke the constructor, but I just need to allocate memory space.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `_header` is a node to implement a circular linked-list, as `std::list` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `Node` to make it default constructible, and you don't want to default construct `T` even if it has a default constructor.  So you can replace `T _item` with:

```
std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> _item;
```

Or in C++23 because `std::aligned_storage` is deprecated:

```
alignas(T) std::byte _item[sizeof(T)];
```

That will give you the storage space you need, with appropriate alignment, and then you'll use placement new to construct `T` in that storage.  You will also need to explicitly invoke `~T()` before or during destruction of each `Node`.

Demo showing the basics, certainly not complete or tested: https://godbolt.org/z/bGaKWb3de

Comment: Note that `aligned_storage` is deprecated in C++23.

Comment: Re: `aligned_storage` being deprecated, see [Why is std::aligned_storage to be deprecated in C++23 and what to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71828288/11082165) for rational and alternatives, and [Why does the use of `std::aligned_storage` allegedly cause UB due to it failing to "provide storage"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71834788/11082165) more on the current UB issues with it.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Wow that's crazy, thanks for pointing it out.  I've added an alternative using `std::byte`.

Comment: `aligned_storage` is just an empty struct. It should be its nested type `type` or the helper struct `aligned_storage_t`.