# How to initialize an array of structs containing reference members?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, c++17

For example:

```cpp
struct thing1 {
    int very_important_integer = 5;
};

struct thing2 {
    thing1 &thing;
    thing2(thing1 &A) : thing(A) {}
};

int main() {
    // in practice, this array is 49,500 elements large, not just 5
    thing1 stuff[5]; // OK
    thing2 arr[5];   // error: no default constructor for thing2
}
```

I can't add a default constructor to `thing2` because there is a reference to be initialized.

Comment: To which objects must the references of the array elements bind?

Comment: An arr of thing1s

Comment: Can you use an initializer list? `thing2 arr[5]{ stuff[0], stuff[1], stuff[2], stuff[3], stuff[4] };`

Comment: I could, but I'm using 45,900 of these. (Don't ask why) ;D

Comment: change the reference to pointer and set it in a while/for loop?

Comment: 45900 array will trigger stack overflow? should use vector instead?

Comment: no ive got big stack

Comment: change the reference to pointer and set it in a while/for loop? genius

Comment: Thank you, @Jan Schultke, for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it is what you want, but it's the only option - init elements at the creation.

```
struct thing1 {
  int veryimportantinteger = 5;
};

struct thing2 {
  thing1& thing;
  thing2(thing1& A) : thing(A) {}
};

int main() {
  thing1 stuff[5];
  thing2 arr[5]{stuff[0], stuff[1], stuff[2], stuff[3], stuff[4]};
}
```

The example with pointers

```
struct thing2 {
  thing1* thing{};
  thing2() = default;
  thing2(thing1& A) : thing(&A) {}
};

int main() {
  thing1 stuff[5];
  thing2 arr[5]{};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(std::size(arr), std::size(stuff)); ++i)
    arr[i] = stuff[i];
}
```

Comment: I hope there might be a better way, and I would accept it, but as mentioned, I hope there is a better way, and perhaps somebody knows it(Most ppl don't answer with accepted ones around). (No offense!)

Comment: Use pointers, that can be zero or default initialized.

Comment: and I'm using 45,900 of these. I could have python type it out while I get lunch tho. XD

Comment: oh ok @273K, could you give an ex?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to explicitly construct each element of `arr[]` yourself, thus allowing you to call the `thing2` constructor on each element, such as in a loop.

Simply pre-allocate a buffer of sufficient size and alignment to hold the objects, then placement-construct each object at the appropriate offset within the buffer, then you can use the objects normally as needed, and then finally destruct the objects and free the buffer when you are done using it.

For example:

```
struct thing1{
  int veryimportantinteger = 5;
};

struct thing2{
  thing1 &thing;
  thing2(thing1 &A):thing(A){}
};

int main(){
  thing1 stuff[5];
  char buffer[sizeof(thing2)*5];
  thing2 *arr = reinterpret_cast<thing2*>(buffer);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    new (&arr[i]) thing2(stuff[i]);
  }
  //use arr as needed...
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    arr[i].~thing2();
  }
}
```

In modern C++, you should use things like  `std::aligned_storage`/`alignas`, `std::launder`, `std::construct_at()`/`std::destroy()`, etc to make this code safer/correct, but the underlying principle still stands.

Comment: `aligned_storage` is deprecated.

Comment: In any case, I don't think this is a good solution. When exceptions become involved, one would need to be very careful to make this exception-safe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know it's deprecated, in C++23, but I dont now what its replacement is

Comment: `alignas(T) char array[sizeof(T)]` is the replacement.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, apparently [I've seen that kind of example before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71828512/65863). That example is  allocating an array which can hold only 1 element, but in this case we would need an array of such elements

Comment: Pedantically, `arr[i]` does pointer arithmetic on non-array, leading to UB... :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 it does point into an array, just make sure the array is aligned properly and don't go out of bounds. This is literally the only way to access objects in `aligned_storage` (which is one of the reasons why it's being deprecated). You could use `aligned_alloc()` or equivalent to allocate the buffer, though.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, fixed

Comment: I really this solution. Provides loop initialization for whatever 45,900 "things" there are. I guess those that are not comfortable with it, are not comfortable with manual memory allocation. Sometimes, that's exactly what you need.

Comment: The thing is..., I come from Java and C# and have no clue what that is or does (and the fact I picked C++ up last month doesn't help)

Comment: @superturkey if you mean the `placemeent-new`, it simply allows you to construct an object at a specific memory address, instead of letting the compiler decide the memory address for you. Hence the use of a preallocated buffer, which the objects are then constructed inside of.

Comment: mostly templates but ill look in to it! great desc tho!

Answer (score 0):

If you change c-array by `std::array`, you might create a function to create the array:

```
// const variant omitted.
// C++20
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename From>
std::array<T, N> make_array_from(std::array<From, N>& froms) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array<T, N>{{T{froms[Is]}...}};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

// C++17
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename From, std::size_t... Is>
std::array<T, N> make_array_from_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::array<From, N>& froms) {
    return std::array<T, N>{{T{froms[Is]}...}};
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename From>
std::array<T, N> make_array_from(std::array<From, N>& froms) {
    return make_array_from_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), froms);
}
```

With usage

```
std::array<thing1, 5> stuff{/*..*/};
auto arr = make_array_from<thing2>(stuff);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mfev8e1G8)

Comment: Note that this is going to have horrendous codegen and compilation speed for 49,500 elements, if it compiles at all (might exceed implementation-defined limits). I'm not sure if there's any way to solve that though.

Comment: @JanSchultke: compiler might have "builtin" to have `index_sequence` in 1 instantiation. So, I don't expected issue in that case (no more than harcoding the array manually).

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that you create an initializer list `{T{froms[Is]}...}` with 49,500 elements. This has catastrophic impact on compile times. The issue of creating an `index_sequence` in the first place is trivial and has been solved by modern compilers, yes. Also, that list initialization does not get merged into a loop; you get the same codegen as a fully unrolled loop with 49,500 iterations, which may be a massive increase in code size. That is, if implementation-defined limits are not exceeded through such a massive list.

Comment: @JanSchultke: *"no more than harcoding the array manually"*. So, that is the problem, ok.