# Does using std::array as storage invoke UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, lifetime, placement-new

Is it okay to use `std::array<std::byte, N> storage` as storage for allocation of some memory?
For example, is it safe to call placement-new on `a.data()`, even though the lifetime of the allocated object has nothing to do with `std::array`?

`std::aligned_storage_t` was [deprecated](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1413r2.pdf) in C++23 for a reason, that it has UB rooted in its design (and poor API but it's not the case in this question), while it's pretty much close to this use case of `std::array`, so is it mandatory to use C-style array `std::byte storage[N]` as a storage for memory allocation, not `std::array` (or maybe even `std::vector`).

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828288/why-is-stdaligned-storage-to-be-deprecated-in-c23-and-what-to-use-instead or answers the question, not sure. Your std::array is not aligned.

Comment: @KamilCuk assuming, that function, that calls placement new, takes care of alignment by adding up to address divisble by alignment of `T`. for example: `std::array<std::byte, 2 * sizeof(std::uint32_t) - 1> arr; std::uint32_t* do_allocate() { new(arr.data() + (sizeof(std::uint32_t) - static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(arr.data()) % sizeof(std::uint32_t)) % sizeof(std::uint32_t)) std::uint32_t(1000); }`, is it UB?

Comment: I see nothing in the linked paper that applies to `std::array`. If you do,  please quote the specific passages you think are relevant.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI it addresses "fails to provide storage" as one of the reasons of UB related to something-something with lifetimes. if this problem is present in `std::aligned_storage_t`, then it's probably present in `std::array`

Comment: An array (C-style) can provide storage. `aligned_*` does not give access to any array. `std_array` does, via its `data()`. So this point is not valid.

Comment: Having said that, if I need an object providing storage, I will probably wrap a C-style array into a lightweight class and use `alignas` for alignment. Leave `std::array` for use as a container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with `std::aligned_storage_t` is that when you start the lifetime of the new object, the lifetime of the `std::aligned_storage_t` object ends. [[basic.life]p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#1.5):

> The lifetime of an object *o* of type `T` ends when:
>
> - [...]
> - the storage which he object occupies [...] is reused by an object that is not nested within *o*.

So if you were to use the `std::array` as if it were `std::aligned_storage_t`, you would not be able to call any of the member functions of the array since the arrays lifetime would end:

```cpp
alignas(T) std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)> arr;
T* ptr = std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&arr), ...);
// Lifetime of `arr` ends
// arr.data();  // UB: lifetime of `std::array` has ended
```

However, since you use the `.data()` pointer of `std::array`, then the lifetime would not end because the member `std::byte[N]` would provide storage for the new object [[intro.object]p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#3):

> If a complete object is created in storage associated with another object e of type “array of *N* `unsigned char`” or of type “array of *N* `std​::​byte`” that array provides storage for the created object if [...]

And by [[intro.object]p4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#4):

> An object *a* is *nested within* another object *b* if:
>
> - *a* is a subobject of *b*, or
> - *b* provides storage for *a*, or
> - the exists an object *c* where *a* is nested within *c*, and *c* is nested within *b*.

So instantiate the second option with *b* = the member `std::byte[N]` of `arr` and *c* = the newly constructed object, and the third option with *c* = the member `std::byte[N]` and *a* = the newly constructed object and *b* = the `std::array<std::byte, N>` object. The newly constructed object is nested within the `std::array`.

So it can be used in the same way as if the object were `std::byte[N]` instead of `std::array<std::byte, N>` (namely to provide storage for a new object that is nested in the array/`std::array`):

```cpp
alignas(T) std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)> arr;
T* ptr = std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<T*>(arr.data()), ...);
// Lifetime of `arr` continues: The array provides storage for the `T` object.
for (std::byte repr : arr) {
    // bytes of the object representation of `*ptr`
}
T* ptr2 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(arr.data());  // Points to the same object as `*ptr`
```

Comment: All the same things are true about C-style arrays.

Comment: It occurs to me that what might be cool is if C++ added a `buffer` context-keyword that we could add to members/things that was a `T` for syntax intents and purposes, but simply didn't construct or destruct automatically.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI which limitations does this introduce? C-style arrays have very limited public API, how can I get an UB with C-style array?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI No, because the `T` object would be nested within the array of `std::byte`: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#4.2

Comment: The underlyinhg array of std::array provides storage and the T object is nested within it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, I made a mistake. Thanks for pointing that out, I am going to edit my answer

Comment: @MooingDuck: `std::optional` comes really close.  Then you need a bit of http://wg21.link/P0352 seasoning

Comment: @MooingDuck Can be nicely achieved with a union: https://godbolt.org/z/5Txzn5q54

Comment: _The issue with `std::aligned_storage_t` is that when you start the lifetime of the new object, the lifetime of the `std::aligned_storage_t` object ends. [basic.life]p1:_ How does it follow from the standard bullet? If it is implemented as https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage#Possible_implementation, the newly created object will be nested within `aligned_storage_t`

Comment: @LanguageLawyer With `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), aligonf(T)> x;`, `std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x), ...)` would end the lifetime of `x` because `reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x)` is a pointer to `x` (not it's first member), and so would be storage associated with `x` which is not an array of unsigned char. If it was `std::construct_at(reinterperpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x))`, then it would be a pointer to the member subobject (because they are pointer-interconvertible), but that would require there to actually be an unsigned char array member, which is unspecified

Comment: @LanguageLawyer storage being "associated" doesn't seem to have a formal definition, but to be nested within the storage has to be "associated" with an array of unsigned char/std::byte, and that would presumably require a pointer to a byte array or pointer to a byte inside a byte array, not a pointer to a thing that contains a byte array (consider if there were other members out of the byte array, surely the intent would be that `struct X { alignas(int) char x[sizeof(int)]; int y; } o;` `std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&o), 0);` ends the lifetime of `x`, where `&o.x` wouldn't)